# Отправка сообщений на почту со страницы сайта

Tags: php

Пытаюсь сделать возможность отправлять сообщения со страницы сайта на почту (типо как вопрос к тех.поддержке). Но сообщение отправляется только с одной почты @gmail.com. Никакие другие не приходят, отправляются, но не доставляются. Вот кусочек кода, через который и отправляет:

```
$mailto = 'dimchick5386@mail.ru';
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
```

````
$subject = "".base64_encode("")."";

$headers = "From: $email\r\nReply-to: $email\r\nContent-type: text/html;charset=utf-8\r\n";

mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $headers);```

Как исправить недоразумение?
````

Comment: Письма скорее всего отправляются, но пападают в спам. Функцией mail лучше не отправлять. Для решения данной проблемы лучше слать письма через smtp (тот-же google и yandex, например). 

1. Можно не парситься, зарегать обычную почтовую учетку
2. Присмотритесь к php классу https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer (там-же есть примеры использования).

Comment: Нюанс в том, что я не рассылаю миллион сообщений на разные почты, а только хочу, чтоб на 1 мою приходили сообщения. SMTP точно подходит для этого?

Comment: Хорошо, с SMTP я вроде разобралась, у моего хостинг-провайдера он есть, все тут хорошо. Как мне в коде сайта организовать отправку сообщений теперь? Я на просторах интернета нигде не видела рукописный код, все через модули/классы. Есть какая-нибудь идея?